# Make Reference Toggle Bold On Click in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to make a reference tag toggle bold when clicked. I know there are many examples online and i tried most of them but i keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

I am writing everything in PHP (I have my reasons) and here is the code:

```
print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
echo <<<JS

$(".boldtrigger").click(function(){
    $(".boldtrigger").toggleClass("bold");
});
JS;

/*Now for Html Part*/
echo "<tr class = 'oddkill' ><td class = 'entry_cell' ><a href = \"javascript: displayRow('context_row_${row_paridy}') \" class = 'boldtrigger' style = 'color:black'>$test</a></td>";
```

I have the css in another file:

```
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I don't understand why it thinks that the 'boldtrigger' class doesn't exist. Can someone help?

Comment: you ran your jquery BEFORE the html for the actual element had been parsed. you need to use a `$(document).ready(...)` block  around the .click stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Firstly, nothing you're asking about is "in PHP".

PHP is a server side language. It's generating HTML and Javascript for your browser - but aside from that it's completely irrelevant to your problem and your question.

---

## Now, to solve your problem

You trying to attach a listener to an element that isn't rendered yet:

```
$(".boldtrigger")
```

This looks for an element whose class is `boldtrigger`, and tries to do stuff with it. But, your element is only rendered after this bit of code.

There are two fixes:

### 1. Event delegation

Using the following code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.boldtrigger', function(){
    $(".boldtrigger").toggleClass("bold");
});
```

You can attach a listener on the body who will wait for events to bubble up *from* `.boldtrigger`. This can work when you need to attach events before elements are on the scene.

[Read more about the idea of event delegation here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

[Check out more about `jQuery.on()` here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)

### 2. Re-order your code

The other option is to move your JavaScript to the bottom of the page, or at least below your HTML:

```
<?php
print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";

echo "<tr class = 'oddkill' ><td class = 'entry_cell' ><a href = \"javascript: displayRow('context_row_${row_paridy}') \" class = 'boldtrigger' style = 'color:black'>$test</a></td>";


/*Now for Js Part*/
echo <<<JS

$(".boldtrigger").click(function(){
    $(".boldtrigger").toggleClass("bold");
});
JS;
```

#### 3. `$(document)ready()`

Nearly any time you use jQuery you want to wrap it in a function that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Some code
});
```

Or this:

```
$(function() {
    // Some code
});
```

[You probably want to brush up on some jQuery basics if you aren't aware of that.](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

[Or, better yet - start with plain old Javascript!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)

If you believe that jQuery is easier than plain/vanilla Javascript - you might be in for a surprise. It's 2016 and we have *tons* of great new APIs that make plain old Javascript pretty cool.

In other words:

## [You really don't need jQuery](https://github.com/ndugger/youdontneedjquery)

---

## As an aside

You maybe want to change your JavaScript code. Right now, every occurence of `.boldtrigger` will toggle that class whenever you click *any* of them.

If you want to toggle only the element being clicked, you might want something closer to this:

```
$(this).toggleClass("bold");
```

[Read more about `this` keyword here](http://www.sitepoint.com/what-is-this-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thank so so much, this isn't the complete code, I only added the relevant stuff so there is PHP stuff used :P